# Looking for alternative to Google Reader sync for RSS app

Tags: rss, synchronization, feed

I'm in the early stages of designing an RSS app, and I'd like to include syncing to an online RSS feed service as a feature. Most such apps make use of Google Reader's feed/syncing features, but Google is now moving sync out of its Reader service, and also its API remains undocumented. Are there any alternatives to Google Reader that offer online syncing of feeds with a desktop client, and which have a documented API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple suggestions, the original web RSS Reader BlogLines is still around, though now under new management since MerchantCircle purchased the service late last year.
The [APIs](http://www.bloglines.com/services/) maybe still functional: 
Or they may be deprecated/turned off, haven't tried the APIs myself.

If BlogLines API is no longer around a better bet is **LiveDoor Reader** (along with it's open sourced version is called FastLadder).

Livedoor Reader is a Japanese service, but FastLadder pages and documentation are available in english and Japanese.

Downloadable Open sourced versions for running on your own machines be they windows, Mac OSX, or Linux from [here](http://fastladder.org/download.html)
There's also a FastLadder Google source Code page.

There are RSS apps for both IOS and Android that sync with LiveDoor Reader/FastLadder instances. Just search for LDR in their respective app stores.

Comment: Since 1.6.2012 FastLadder is closed. Didn't have the chance to try it out.

Answer (score 4):

There *should* be an answer to this question, but I don't think there is.

I think we got lazy. Maybe it's time to roll up our sleeves and get to work.

Comment: This is what I was trying to noodle at in my comments at your blog. What's the alternative? Happy to help build one. We're working on an RSS ingest solution that's small scale right now, but could scale out pretty easily. The hard question is how to sustain the costs. Would the app vendors be willing to pay for this service? Not sure what their business models look like.

Comment: This should either be a pay for service or an open source vm "app" (or both).  It should be a service to pay for because that keeps the vendor-customer relationship honest and straightforward.  It should be open source so that such a system could be decentralized.  It could be both because you would be paying for hosting, not for the software.

Answer (score 3):

What about Newsblur?

http://www.newsblur.com/

Don't know anything about them, but they appear to have a reasonable facsimile of a product in this vein.

Here are their API docs.  http://www.newsblur.com/api

They are a subscription service, but you can have up to 64 feeds for free.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a ready answer yet, but I think Brent Simmons has a rough spec of what could be a start:

http://inessential.com/2010/02/08/idea_for_alternative_rss_syncing_system

Basically, imagine a server that manages feed subscription lists and captures annotations for feed items. Those annotations for items would be things like (un)read, starred, shared, saved, deleted, or whatever else an app might want to attach to a feed item. It should stay simple and not fetch or process feeds themselves - other apps and libraries do that fine already.

Answer (score 0):

Feedlooks looks close too with no ties to Google Reader - not sure about the API, though
http://www.feedlooks.com/

Years back, I'd used a self hosted Open Source app called Gregarious - It appears to have gone missing recently.

Here's the Gregarious Archive from 2010
http://web.archive.org/web/20100925221312/http://gregarius.net/

Another contender for the do-it-yourselfer might be utilizing SimplePie.org