# Is there a feed parsing API like Google Readers?

Tags: api-key, google-reader

https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/FEEDHERE?output=json&n=20

I'm using this right now to parse RSS and Atom feeds, for a lot of reasons. But there is no official API key or something so I'm afraid something may break in the future, like Google stopping my access if I make a lot of queries.

Is there an alternative to this with API keys?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying out [Simplepie](http://simplepie.org/), I wrote a nice RSS reader with it once. Pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple alternatives.

- There's [Feedly](http://feedly.com/). It’s not the minimalistic, omnipresent glory that is Google Reader, but it’s close, and in some ways exceeds Reader’s capabilities. They've got even a [guide for transitioning](http://blog.feedly.com/2013/03/14/google-reader/).
- There's [NewsBlur](http://www.newsblur.com/). It's developed "in the open", aka you can just check it out on their [GitHub](https://github.com/samuelclay).
- There's [Netvibes](http://www.netvibes.com/en). However. Unlike Feedly there's no simple import route in Netvibes for integrating your Google Reader subscriptions. Instead, you need to export your Reader subscriptions as a .ZIP file, extract them to find the 'Subscriptions.xml' file and then import that into Netvibes.
- There's also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890814/looking-for-alternative-to-google-reader-sync-for-rss-app) on the same subject on Stack Overflow.
- And there's many more, just do a Google search.

In my (and many others') opinion, Feedly's the best alternative. But each their own. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try [Google Feed Api](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/), it is easy to use. It supports JSON and XML formats, but it is limited to a maximum of 250 feeds per url.